# Elements saved to and retrieved from a file

Tags: list, file, element

a very noob question, but I am simply trying to enter data into a file(as individual elements) and then retrieve them as individual elements to put into a list, not one large string.

So far, all I have managed to do is to save the data into a file and when I go to retrieve it, it comes out as one large string (no \t or \n or anything I can use to splice with).  Python 3 for absolute beginners and google searches have yet to help me solve the problem.  I search on this site has not come up with anything I can understand.

Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code for reading and writing a text file

```py
# For writing to a text file 
f= open("demo.txt","w+")
for i in range(5):
     f.write("This is line {}\n".format(i+1))
f.close() 

# For reading a text file and store the lines to a list
f=open("demo.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    ls = []
    ch = ""
    contents =f.read()

    for i in contents:
        if i != "\n":
            ch += i
        else:
            ls.append(ch)
            ch = ""
    print(ls)
```

NB : When writing a line to a file please make sure to give `\n` at the end to denote a new line.